# Image not show in laravel project

Tags: laravel

Now, I working on Laravel project but i got some issue in this project. I stored image name in database and also store in storage folder but images are not show in my dashboard

[image]

Blade file code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <a href="blog_detail/{{ $main_blog->id }}">
    <img src="<?php echo asset("../storage/app/assets/upload/images/$main_blog->image")?>" class="blog_img">
    <h1 class="blog_main_heading">{{ $main_blog->title }}</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your folder structure, hope it works though, Please check below code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <a href="blog_detail/{{ $main_blog->id }}">
    <img src="{{ Storage::url('app/assets/upload/images/'. $main_blog->image) }}" class="blog_img">
    <h1 class="blog_main_heading">{{ $main_blog->title }}</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can u share your storage link

Comment: also u can try again like this: {{ Storage::url('assets/upload/images/'. $main_blog->image) }}

Comment: $img = $request->file('image')->store('assets/upload/images/');
       
$all_data['image'] =  $request->file('image')->store('');

Comment: It's work properly in local server but i got issue only in live server

Comment: can u share your project live url

Comment: https://beyondedu.in/blog

Comment: Did you change the folder structure while deploying the project to Live Server?

Comment: no i did't change any folder structure while deploy the project on live server

Answer (score 2):

if your image `storage path` is like this then this will work for you.
**public/assets/images/default.png**

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/default.png')}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ url(asset('images').'/'.$img_name) }}
```

instead of images use your path and try . Please check image exists in your server

Answer (score 1):

First, It is worthwhile to mention that your code is a bad practice. It would be better to do something like this in the controller, say `ImageController`

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    private $storagePath;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->storagePath = Storage::disk('public')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    }

    public function index(){
         $images = Image::all();
         $storagePath = $this->storagePath;
         return view('index', compact('images', 'storagePath'));
    }
}
```

Then in blade

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <a href="blog_detail/{{ $main_blog->id }}">
            <img src="{{ $storagePath . $main_blog->image) }}" class="blog_img">
            <h1 class="blog_main_heading">{{ $main_blog->title }}</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
```

and about the problem, you should inspect the missed images and see what the url is. Check whether it works with `/public` suffix in url or not. Let us see the `filesystem.php`. This is mine

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'temp' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/temp'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

Appropriately set this file and make sure storage link is ran on the production server. Anyway, we need more details to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, `asset()` helper is based on your APP_URL, means you are trying to access storage path directly, that won't work because you cannot access out of public folder.

So, make sure you done `php artisan storage:link` whens you doing that it will create a link from your storage to public, and you can see storage folder under your public folder, then you can just use like this `asset('storage/app/assets/upload/images/filename.png')`.

If you didn't find storage folder in your public folder that means your link build failed.

Answer (score -1):

Show your image uri in the web page, copy and paste image uri to check image uri is correct

Did you use `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: yes i used this command